# Generators of a quotient ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I, J$ be monomial ideals. The quotient ideal is defined as $I:J = [ f\in S | fg \in I  \forall g\in J ].$ Also it holds that $I:J = \cap_{v\in G(J)} I:(v),$ where $G(J)$ is a set of minimal generators of J.

> I need to prove that the set $[ u/\gcd(u,v)| u\in G(I) ]$ is a set of generators of $I: (v).$

We may assume first that $w \in I:(v).$ I am wondering if one can claim that there exists an element $u \in G(I)$ such that $u$ divides $wv$. I also do not understand what does it mean $u/\gcd(u,v).$

In case of $\mathbb{Z}$ it does not hold, for example $3\mid (2 \cdot 6)$ but $3$ does not divide $\gcd(2,6) = 2.$

I do not know how to go from here.

Can you provide a proof or provide some suggestions?

Thanks.